# What country has the highest requirements for loans?

Tags: finance, banking, investment, debt

I was looking to find countries with the toughest regulations on loans(general loans not any specific ones)

By that I mean:
 I mainly care to know where it is toughest for people to get a loan from a bank.

To consider is:

•   where requirements are highest for people to qualify for a loan

•   where banks do the most thorough checks in a persons financial status (like SCHUFA in Germany)

•   where do banks have to pass the most audits and tests to prove their business is legit

I was looking at IWF Data but could not really get that sort of info from there.

I am basically looking to invest in Banks and want to find the best country to do that based on their banking infrastructure. I want to find lenders that make SURE their clients pay by setting the bar very high (I know that doesn’t mean they won’t default anyways)

Comment: Requirements are multimetric, so neither "highest requirements" nor "most thorough checks" nor "toughest regulations" are well defined here. Also, this does not really seem to be a question about the discipline of economics.

Comment: Perspective. So you are saying a countries economic standing have nothing to do with how easy or hard it is to take on debt there ? I you need me to define it more or is unclear to you I will explain

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point would be the "[getting credit](http://www.doingbusiness.org/en/data/exploretopics/getting-credit)" subindex of the Doing Business rankings compiled by the World Bank.  There is also an [explanation of the methodology](http://www.doingbusiness.org/en/methodology/getting-credit).  This is supposed to be a test of the business environment, i.e. rules laid down by the government and central bank rather than about the behaviour of market participants.